# How to recognize one finger drag on trackpad on mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, multi-touch, trackpad

I'm having some troubles reading trackpad events. I need to catch a single tap and a drag of one finder on trackpad. And also to distinguish them. Catching a single tap is working like this:

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    CGFloat wdev2  = self.bounds.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat hdev2 = self.bounds.size.height / 2;

    NSPoint point = [theEvent locationInWindow];

    float x = (point.x - wdev2) / wdev2;
    float y = (point.y - hdev2) / hdev2;

    [_touchHandler handleMouseTouch:x And:y];
}
```

but how to recognize a drag? I tried `mouseDragged:` and that's giving me three finder pan event.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to use [`mouseDragged`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSGestureRecognizer/mouseDragged:) *in addition to* [`NSGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSGestureRecognizer).

<sub>***mouseDragged***:</sub>

> ***The default implementation of this method does nothing***. Use this
>   method to update the state of your gesture recognizer in whatever way
>   is appropriate.
>
> A gesture recognizer monitors events that occur in its view (and any
>   subviews) but does not take part in the responder chain itself. The
>   gesture recognizer receives events before any views do. Use the
>   delaysPrimaryMouseButtonEvents property to control whether event is
>   propagated to the view.

Used with `NSGestureRecognizer` you should be able to get your desired effect.

↳ [AppKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001093) > [NSGestureRecognizer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSGestureRecognizer)

Comment: Some experiments I did with those but, unfortunately, couldn't get desired behavior. And the point is that it's working with mouse (click, click+drag) as expected, but not with trackpad..